# Display accented characters in an SVG object in an html page

Tags: html, svg, character-encoding

Accented characters (acute e etc) do not display in my svg object within an html page. The page is declared:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> ..
```

and the SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
```

What's my big mistake?

Comment: What content-encoding is the SVG file served with? What accented characters are you talking about since there's none in your question.

Comment: The SVG file has encoding="ISO-8859-1".  acute e is é (which displays as an unknown character.)

Comment: (1) Make sure the characters in your SVG are in the correct character encoding.  (2) Are you using an unusual font that doesn't include the accented glyphs?

Comment: Many thanks for looking at this.  The same characters display correctly in the html outside the SVG. The font in the SVG is Arial, so should display perfectly too.  The essence of the question is what the SVG header should contain so that the SVG is consistent with the html: ie it displays the same characters in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

does this show up right for you?

```html
<svg>
  <text y="15">äöüëèéê</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Text containing accented characters including these causes the svg object to fail to display in the browser.

Comment: -- or, if the svg object does display, then as an unknown character

Comment: It works fine for me.  Check your browser settings?  Or another browser.

Comment: When these characters are contained in an inline svg element, or called in an object <object type="image/svg+xml" data="test.svg"></object>

Comment: **[Ignore previous comment - edits were timed out]**

Thanks for your thoughts. I found that these characters are correctly displayed either when in an inline svg element, or when called in an object: 

<object type="image/svg+xml" data="test.svg"></object>

However the file fails to display, or these characters are displayed as unknown characters, when the same file is called in an img:

<img src="test.svg">

(which is the recommended method for svgs in asp.net).

Comment: As others mentioned before,  I suspect that you stated encoding does not match the real encoding of the file... do you have a link to the file for us to check?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that if your linked svg file includes accented characters then in asp.net you should use an object:

```
<object type='image/svg+xml' data='<%#Container.DataItem("FieldName")%>'></object>
```

rather than the otherwise recommended image:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("FieldName")%>'/>
```